# Advertising Jobs on Stack Overflow Careers on my blog

Tags: support, jobs, advertising

I started reading some blogs by Joel and Jeff, and noticed that there are ads for Careers on SO. Is the little banner available for other users to use? Does it generate any referral fees for the person adding the banner? Or is this just because they created it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Joel and Jeff as the co-founders of Stack Exchange run those ads on their blogs and they're totally custom. We don't have any referral program.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @CanadianLuke: No prob.

Comment: Semi-related question: any plans to support such an agreement with other users?